# How to convert a Variant (containing an array) to an array, to pass it as a parameter?

Tags: arrays, delphi, variant

I need to call a function expecting an `array of Integer`, but I have my values in a variable of type `Variant`, containing the array.

Do I really have to copy the values in a loop? I couldn't find a better way that works.

The same variant can also hold a single `Integer` instead of the array, so I created a helper function allowing both (checking with `VarIsArray`). It works, but it is just lengthy and not nice :)

```
type
  TIntegerArray = array of Integer;

function VarToArrayInt(const V: Variant): TIntegerArray;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if VarIsArray(V) then begin
    SetLength(Result, VarArrayHighBound(V, 1) + 1);
    for I:= 0 to High(Result) do Result[I]:= V[I];
  end else begin
    SetLength(Result, 1);
    Result[0]:= V;
  end;
end;
```

I'm using Delphi 10.2.2 and the function to be called cannot be changed and looks like this:

```
function Work(Otherparameters; const AParams: array of Integer): Boolean;
```

Comment: I would really appreciate it if downvoters could leave a short explanation and what I should have done better. This is a real question, I found a working solution myself, but I hoped for and got a much better one and also learned a lot. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately there is no need for a loop, at least when the array is 0-based.

If the called function would expect a dynamic array, you could just pass the Variant as it is. You can also directly assign it to a dynamic array variable.

In your case it is an open array parameter, and that needs casting in this case.

Here is some demonstration of what is possible and how, including a nice and short helper function allowing both arrays and single values.

```
program Test;

uses Variants;

procedure PrintOpenArray(const Arr: array of Integer); {open array parameter}
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I in Arr do Writeln(I);
end;

procedure PrintDynamicArray(const Arr: TArray<Integer>); {dynamic array param}
begin
  PrintOpenArray(Arr);
end;

function VarToArrayInt(const V: Variant): TArray<Integer>;
begin
  if VarIsArray(V) then Result:= V else Result:= [V];
  {[V] works only in XE7 and up. You can use TArray<Integer>.Create(V) instead}
end;

type  {dynamic integer array, but only compatible to this type}
  TIntegerArray = array of Integer;

var
  V: Variant;
  A: TArray<Integer>; {dynamic array, compatible to any other TArray<Integer>}
begin {all the following only works with 0-based arrays!}
  V:= VarArrayCreate([0, 2], varInteger);
  V[0]:= 1;
  V[1]:= 2;
  V[2]:= 3;

  A:= V; {Variant can just be assigned to dynamic array if it contains an array}
  PrintOpenArray(A);

  PrintDynamicArray(V); {works directly without casting}
  PrintOpenArray(TArray<Integer>(V)); {not possible without casting}
  PrintOpenArray(TIntegerArray(V));
  PrintOpenArray(VarToArrayInt(V));

  V:= 4; {demonstration of helper function to allow arrays and single values}
  PrintOpenArray(VarToArrayInt(V));
  PrintDynamicArray(VarToArrayInt(V));

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: This is not efficient. Memory copies all over the place. A by value open array parameter guarantees a memory copy. Is that really what you want.

Comment: This just shows multiple possibilities. What is your suggestion? How is it possible to solve the question without copying memory? Source data is in a variant, and target is a function with open array parameter. @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Note that the `Result := [V];` syntax only works in XE7 and newer.

Comment: There are methods in the Variants unit that give you access to the raw data.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I'd like to add a comment with a pre-XE7 example, but I don't know if there is an easier way than SetLength 1 and [0]:=V?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, for educational reasons I'd be very interested to see an efficient solution which passes the raw data to the open array without copying it. However, since I happen to know the questioner, I can say that if it's not as nice to read, he won't use it. Maybe you could post another answer or give me more hints how it could be done? Btw., there is another open question: is there also a nice solution when the source array is 1-based?

Comment: @maf-soft: "since I happen to know the questioner"  Are you saying that the q is actually from someone eles despite being posted from your account?

Comment: @MartynA, maybe I shouldn't try to be funny in english, which is not my mother language. It is my own question, which came up at work and you can see the working loop-solution. In my free time I looked for a better solution, did some investigations and learned a lot about different arrays and variants. So I decided to try to help the community by posting question and answer. Since I already got multiple down votes for this, I'd maybe think twice next time...

Comment: I don't see a reason for downvotes. No Delphi here at work, so I can't try it, but it that works, it is a very good answer, IMO. You already had my upvote.

Comment: @maf-soft: what about `Result := TArray<Integer>.Create(V)`; as the pre-XE7 alternative for a variant with a single Integer value? That generates exactly the same code as `Result := [V];` and as `"SetLength(Result, 1); Result[0] := V;`. All the same, just a different syntax.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, great, I added it as a comment in the code. I already found the same yesterday, tried it, but code completion couldn't find `.Create`. Because I was in a hurry I gave up. Now I tried again manually and it compiles and works :)

Answer (score 5):

If the function takes an `array of Integer` as a separate type, eg:

```
type
  TIntegerArray = array of Integer;

function DoIt(const Values: TIntegerArray): ReturnType;
```

Then the function takes a [Dynamic Array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) as input.  You can assign/pass a `Variant` holding an array to a Dynamic Array variable/parameter.  The compiler is smart enough to call the RTL's `VarToDynArray()` function to allocate a new Dynamic Array that has a copy of the `Variant`'s array elements.  There is no way to pass a `Variant` holding an array to a Dynamic Array without making a copy of the array data.

However, if the function takes an `array of Integer` directly in its parameter list instead, eg:

```
function DoIt(const Values: array of Integer): ReturnType;
```

Then it takes an [Open Array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Open_Arrays) as input:

> an Delphi function that has an open array parameter can be called by explicitly passing two parameters:
>
> - A pointer to the first element of the array
> - A count, which is the value of the last index (that is, the size/number of array elements, minus one)"

You can't pass a `Variant` (whether it holds an array or not) directly to an Open Array parameter.  The compiler is not smart enough to extract the array pointer and element count and pass them to the Open Array parameter.  However, you can do it manually with a little typecast trickery, eg:

```
function DoIt(const Values: array of Integer): ReturnType;

...

type
  TOpenArrayFunc = function(const Values: PInteger; ValuesHigh: Integer): ReturnType;

var
  V: Variant;
  Count: Integer;
  P: PInteger;
begin
  ...
  V := ...;
  Count := VarArrayHighBound(V, 1) - VarArrayLowBound(V, 1) + 1;
  P := VarArrayLock(V);
  try
    TOpenArrayFunc(@DoIt)(P, Count-1);
  finally
    VarArrayUnlock(V);
  end;
  ...
end;
```

This passes the `Variant`'s array directly to the function without making any copies of the array elements at all.

Comment: Yes, it is an open array - otherwise the question wouldn't have come up because it would have worked the way I tried it first :) Great to see that it is possible without copying memory. Thanks! However, the to-be-called function has many more other parameters, _and_ there are 2 different ones I have to call, so I'd prefer a conversion function that returns the array as a return value so I can use it easily in both places. Last but not least, my concrete case is about a maximum of 5 values, so that performance really doesn't matter. I will use the solution with the most readable and short code.

Comment: It you add a short and nice copy-memory-solution on top of your answer (because that's what the question was about), and give the other interesting info only as further info, I'd set this as accepted answer, since your explanations are better and spiced with helpful links...

Comment: @maf-soft if you want to avoid copying memory, you can simply define additional function types with relevant parameters to typecast function calls to. But it is not possible to write a conversion function to populate an open array parameter without copying memory. Any type of array can be passed to an open array parameter, and you already have a conversion function to convert a `Variant` to a dynamic array.